How to add methods to query an object in mongoose using typescript?
The problem is more related to the typescript. I need these methods to check the returned result after querying the db.
const user = await User.findOne({idUser: 1}).isAbsent(400)// this status code http

I would like to ask if it is a good practice that has created such methods. The point of this method is to reduce the amount of code written, since there is no need to check the existence of the returned document and return an exception. If the document is not found, an exception is raised. I also need access to the context from the isAbsent() method to the request in order to get the name of the model through which the request was made
I tried to do this through plugins that are in mongoose, but alas I did not find a way to extend the Query class type.
isAbsent(schema: Schema) {
    schema.query.isAbsent = async function(statusCode) {
      const doc = await this.exec()
      if (!doc) {
        throw ApiError(statusCode)
      }
      return doc
    }
  }

The error occurred: Property 'isAbsent' does not exist on type '{}'. This question is similar to @markitusss question, but I use typescript.
This my ts-config:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots": ["src/typings", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/typings/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules, ./src/@types"]
}


Extend Mongoose Query Interface
  import { Query } from 'mongoose';
    
    declare module 'mongoose' {
      interface Query<ResultType, DocType, THelpers = {}> {
        isAbsent(statusCode: number): Promise<DocType>;
      }
    }

Now, implement the isAbsent() method in a Mongoose plugin:
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

function isAbsentPlugin(schema: Schema) {
  schema.query.isAbsent = async function (statusCode: number) {
    const doc = await this.exec(); // `this` refers to the query
    if (!doc) {
      throw new ApiError(statusCode); // Replace ApiError with your custom error class
    }
    return doc;
  };
}

export default isAbsentPlugin;

Apply this plugin to your schema
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import isAbsentPlugin from './isAbsentPlugin';

const userSchema = new Schema({
  idUser: { type: Number, required: true },
  // other fields...
});

userSchema.plugin(isAbsentPlugin);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

Now you can use isAbsent() in your queries
const user = await User.findOne({ idUser: 1 }).isAbsent(400);


The error remains the same: Property 'isAbsent' does not exist on type '{}'. I have attached ts-config to the question.
And in which file should the declarations be located? I have them in the typings folder.
The same Query that I import into the mongoose.d file.ts is not used in the declaration itself. Like an extra import (lit in gray). I would like to ask if it is a good practice to extend object types into libraries
